# How can I make a required field work only when clicking in the button submit?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a form with a table that the user will register all clients that he wants to put there. And I am using a required field validator for two textboxes which the user will have to fill with the information. But the problem is when I want to update the textbox with new information, the required fields ask me to fill them with new text, and those are not from the textbox that I am editing.

The problem appears here :

[image]

The form requires me to fill the other textbox below if I want to update the other ones, but I want that when I am updating a textbox it does not require me to fill the other textbox.

My code :

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome do Cliente">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblClienteNome" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_nome")%>'/>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                            <EditItemTemplate>                         
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtclienteNome" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_nome")%>'/>                           
                            </EditItemTemplate>

                            <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbnome" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valName" ControlToValidate = "txtbnome"
runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "E-mail do Cliente">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblClienteEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_email")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtclienteEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_email")%>'/>
                            </EditItemTemplate>

                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtbemail" runat="server"/>
                                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate = "txtbemail"
runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required" />
                                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="AddNew" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-large btn-info pull-right">
                                     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> &nbsp; Adicionar
                                 </asp:LinkButton>
                            </FooterTemplate>
```

How can I make it not ask me to fill the other textboxes when I am updating the fields?

Comment: Assuming these two sets of fields are submitted using different buttons, you can use different ValidationGroups to specify which fields are validated by which actions. You set a ValidationGroup attribute on the button e.g. `ValidationGroup="AddNew", and put the same on any validation controls that must only be validated when that button is pressed.

Then you can do the same, if necessary for your other fields and buttons

Comment: @ADyson, just saw your comment - my thoughts exactly! Took me longer to type up my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You can associate your `RequiredFieldValidator` controls with a specific [ValidationGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx); then associate the same `ValidationGroup` with the corresponding `Button` or `LinkButton`:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valName" ControlToValidate = "txtbnome"
   runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="AddNew" runat="server" 
    CssClass="btn btn-large btn-info pull-right"  ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> &nbsp; Adicionar
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Each `LinkButton` will cause the `RequiredFieldValidator` controls in their own `ValidatorGroup` to run when clicked; others will not run.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a custom Attribute:

```
public class ButtonRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    private readonly string _buttonName;

    public ButtonRequiredAttribute(string buttonName)
    {
        _buttonName = buttonName;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var form = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;

        //only validating if "add"-Button is pressed
        if (form[_buttonName] != null)
        {
            return base.IsValid(value);
        }

        //When no "add"-Button is pressed, no validation is needed
        return true;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
[ButtonRequiredAttribute("NameOfYourButton")]
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to use this custom attribute (expand your example to include some more code as to where you'd add the attribute), and how this technique will help with client-side validation upon submit?

Comment: That's [DataAnnotations](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/data-annotations-for-web-forms-in-net-4-5/). For Client Validation `IClientValidatable` must be implemented. @CoolBots

Answer (score 0):

All answers here were very useful to me, but I found a simpler way to solve my problem.

I forgot to show the code of the two buttons, update and delete, with them I simply used the property of `CausesValidation` to let when I clicked on them, to be not required to fill in the texts to update or delete.

So, my code with the two buttons is now something like that :

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="true" CausesValidation="False"/>
```

To more information, I found it here in this link to be helpful :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx